# AWS CLI update CNAME value

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-route53

I want to change the value of a CNAME record in Route53 using the AWS CLI.

But, I am unsure what parameter to use with the command:

```
aws route53 change-resource-record-sets /
--hosted-zone-id [MY HOSTED ZONE ID]
```

I retrieve the record with the following command:

```
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets /
--hosted-zone-id [MY HOSTED ZONE ID] /
--query ResourceRecordSets[?Name == 'example.abccloud.com.']
```

And, the output is as follows:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "example.abccloud.com.",
        "Type": "CNAME",
        "TTL": 300,
        "ResourceRecords": [
            {
                "Value": "internal-example-alb-12345.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Now, I want to change the CNAME value:

Old CNAME Value: "internal-example-alb-12345.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com"

New CNAME Value: "internal-example-alb-67891.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com"

Answer (score 0):

Create a file similar to the following (example:  /tmp/cname.json ):

```
    {   
    "Changes": 
        [ 
            { "Action": "UPSERT", "ResourceRecordSet": 
                { "Name": "internal-example-alb-12345", "Type": "CNAME", "AliasTarget":
                    { 
                        "HostedZoneId": "YOURHOSTEDZONEID","DNSName": "internal-example-alb-67891.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com","EvaluateTargetHealth": false 
                    } 
                } 
            }   
        ]
}
```

Then invoke the command you've specified as follows:

> aws route53 change-resource-record-sets 
> --hosted-zone-id /hostedzone/YOURHOSTEDZONEID 
> --change-batch file:///tmp/cname.json

Details can be found on Amazon's AWS cli pages:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/alias-resource-record-set-route53-cli/